# Flutter: Google SignIn without Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google SignIn in flutter without using Firebase.

I am using Google SignIn package, taking idToken from there and sending it to my backend API for authentication.

I am getting pop up for selecting user email but after selecting, I am getting following error:

```
error: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null)
```

Below is my code in BLoC for handling Google SignIn:

```
if (event is GoogleSignInButtonPressed) {
      yield LoginInProgress();

      try {
        GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes:['email']);
        GoogleSignInAccount user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
        print(user);
        GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await user.authentication;
        String idToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;

        final token = await userRepository.authenticateWithGoogleSignIn(idToken: idToken);

        authenticationBloc.add(AuthenticationLoggedIn(token: token));
        yield LoginInitial();
      } catch (error) {
        yield LoginFailure(error: error.toString());
      }
```

Comment: did you complete the oauth consent screen part?

Comment: I signed the app and registered it on developers console. Still, I am getting this error.

How to complete the oauth consent screen part?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase isn't required to use Google Sign-in. You can use [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) plugin to authenticate the user. The ApiException that you're getting likely comes from not [configuring the app](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#platform-integration) properly on the Google Could API dashboard. Ensure that you've filled all the required fields on the [OAuth console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent).